# Flutter - Unable to signin with Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, flutter

My Android Flutter app has Google sign-in using Firebase Authentication. Everything works great in debug mode, but fails in release mode. I have added my SHA-1 fingerprints for both debug and release keystores in the Firebase console, and have updated to the latest google-services.json.

The problem seems to be that I am never getting a FirebaseUser back. This method always returns null:

```
Future<FirebaseUser> _getCurrentUser() async {
  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  if (firebaseAuth.currentUser() != null) {
    return await firebaseAuth.currentUser();
  }

  return null;
}
```

The codelabs example isn't working either. It is returning a GoogleSignInUser, but it's not creating a Firebase user in the console:

```
Future<GoogleSignInAccount> _ensureLoggedIn() async {
  GoogleSignInAccount user = _googleSignIn.currentUser;
  if (user == null) user = await _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  if (user == null) {
    user = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    analytics.logLogin();
  }
  if (_auth.currentUser == null) {
    GoogleSignInAuthentication credentials =
        await _googleSignIn.currentUser.authentication;
    await _auth.signInWithGoogle(
      idToken: credentials.idToken,
      accessToken: credentials.accessToken,
    );
  }

  return user;
}
```

I have implemented Firebase Authentication before in a native Android app just fine. I have read several other stack overflow posts about this, but I feel like I have tried everything. Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

In a release build, I can read and write to the database if I don't set any read/write rules. I am still unable to create a FirebaseUser. I can create a GoogleSignInAccount, but that doesn't create a Firebase user.

Comment: have you enabled the google sign in in firebase?

Comment: @WahdatKashmiri Yes. Debug builds work fine. It's only release builds that aren't working.

Comment: Do you have an error reporting enabled so you get exception output from the application?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes. It is only telling me that my FirebaseUser is null, so I am getting this error when calling user.email:  NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'email' was called on null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it working. I just updated all of my dependencies to the latest versions and targeted the latest version of android, then updated my project using this [guide](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Updating-Flutter-projects-to-Gradle-4.1-and-Android-Studio-Gradle-plugin-3.0.1) and authenticated with Firebase the same way as in this [example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/example/lib/main.dart).

These are my dependencies:

```
google_sign_in: 2.0.0
firebase_analytics: 0.2.0
firebase_auth: 0.4.0
firebase_database: 0.3.1
firebase_admob: 0.2.2
```

Hope this helps somebody!